# Can't find lhdf5 while installing caffe

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, hdf5

I'm getting this error message when I try to run the make file for caffe.

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:567: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I've tried symbolic linking as per these [instructions](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide) but to no avail. I've read other posts on hdf5 and looked at the symbolic links in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Aug 29 16:43 hdf5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6075302 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       21 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_cpp.so -> libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       21 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_cpp.so.11 -> libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   402080 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    40108 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_hl_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.11.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.11 -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.11.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    14688 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.11.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Oct 19 08:59 libhdf5_hl.so -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19953086 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1659560 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       32 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       32 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   238408 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   878832 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   515320 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       34 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       34 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    80520 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   126232 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     3859 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.settings
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Oct 19 08:57 libhdf5.so -> libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
```

I don't see any issues. How would I reinstall hdf5?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050804

Comment: Will that work with hdf5?

Comment: have you installed hdf5 from source or with apt-get?

Comment: I installed libhdf5-serial-dev with apt-get according to caffe instructions.

Comment: try this commands `find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's^"hdf5.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5.h"^g' -e 's^"hdf5_hl.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.h"^g' '{}' \;

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0 libhdf5.so

sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2 libhdf5_hl.so 
`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the linker is looking for `libhdf5_cpp.so` but you only have `libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0`

A quick hack is to symlink `libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0` to `libhdf5_cpp.so`

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       21 Oct 20 12:35 libhdf5_cpp.so -> libhdf5_cpp.so.11.0.0` I've created a symlink like you suggested but I'm still getting the error. Any ideas? `AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:567: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1`

Comment: The `fileName.so` is a symlink to `fileName.so.11.0.0` too. This way, you can have several versions of a library in your system, and if an application needs a specific one, it can link to it, while in general, the newest one is chosen by symlink.